# What is true translation of CCCP - Cryptographic Computational Continuation Passing?

Tags: перевод

This is the name of paper, I'm currently can't find concrete source, but it is used everywhere, try to google it, it is every where. E.g. in this [paper](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~negin/projects.html).

> Cryptographic Computational Continuation Passing (CCCP),

As a rule recommend, translation start from the end of sentences, vice verse:

> Переход Продолжительный   Вычислительный Криптографический

Am I right?

Answer (score 5):

'[Computational] continuation' in this context is a concept from functional programming which, AFAIK, has not yet gained a well-established translation in Russian. Many sources use 'продолжение [вычислений]'.

Thus, the whole phrase may be translated as 'криптографическая передача продолжений вычислений' or 'шифрованная передача продолжений вычислений' or 'шифрованный обмен продолжениями вычислений'.

Answer (score 0):

> Продолжительная Вычислительная Криптографическая Передача

and here is the paper [CCCP: SECURE REMOTE STORAGE FOR COMPUTATIONAL RFIDS](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/sec09/tech/full_papers/salajegheh.pdf)

Comment: Have you translated it yourself, or you have seen such translation somewhere? Adding this info will make your answer better.